# Proving that $f^3$ is constant if $f^2(z) = \overline {f(z)}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, analytic-functions

Good morning! I have a question on how to show this.

> Let $f$ be analytic on a non-empty domain $D$. If $f^2(z) = \overline {f(z)}$ for all $z \in D$ then prove that $f^3$ is constant in $D$. Deduce that $f$ is also constant in $D$.

I'm thinking of proving by contradiction (i. e., $f^3$ is non-constant) and using the open mapping theorem here by considering an open set $U \subseteq D$ which maps into an open map. But I don't know how to move on from here.

Comment: If $f^2=\overline f$ then $f^3=f\overline f=|f|^2$ is real-valued.

Comment: Good evening! If you multiply by $f$ you'll get $f^3=|f|^2$, meaning that the analytic function $f^3$ is, in fact, *real-valued*. Conclusion?

Comment: Oh, a real-valued function on a connected set is constant! Thanks!

Comment: You could also avoid the trick and go with the identity $$\frac{\partial \overline f}{\partial \overline z}=\overline{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}}$$ to show that $\overline f$ is holomorphic only if $f$ is constant (and therefore, $f^2$ constant et cetera).